# Creating a List using the concrete type's Class

Tags: java, list, generics, reflection

I can understand the example of instantiating a `List` object using a generic type. My current homework assignment involves creating an `Appender` for Log4j that stores the logs in a list. One of the requirements is that the user could specify a concrete implementation of `List` for the constructor and I have done this by just accepting a `List` that they have created.

Is there a way to make it so that they can provide the `Class<T>` implementing `List` that they want to be using and my constructor will instantiate a new instance of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class<T>` will let you call [`newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--), which will return you a `T`. If you then combine this with [wildcard generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) you could in theory specify a `Class<? extends List<LoggingEvent>>` and create any type that implements the `List<LoggingEvent>` interface.

However here is the first problem: you [cannot use a parameterized type with the class literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) (i.e. `LinkedList<LoggingEvent>.class` will not compile). Therefore you have to relax your method/constructor parameter to only bound the wildcard on the raw type of `List`, like this: `Class<? extends List>`.

So now when you create the `List` you will have to cast it to the correct generic type. That will mean you need to do [unchecked conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9) using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. <strike>In this case this is safe to do as you will never try and use that raw type as any other generic type other than `List<LoggingEvent>`.</strike> <sup>†</sup>

The final implementation would look something like:

```
class LogStore {
    private List<LogLine> loggingEvents = null;
    public LogStore(Class<? extends List> clazz) {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<LogLine> logStoreList = clazz.newInstance();
            this.loggingEvents = logStoreList;
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

<sup>†</sup> In this case this may be safe to do so if you provide the user with a set of prompts to let them choose a standard `List<LoggingEvent>` implementation, but if they are going to use this as an API and you have no control over which `Class<? extends List>` they pass in then you have two choices: either let the api fail at runtime in unpredictable places, or try and check the type argument for list. However, even if you do check the type argument you cannot check for all eventualities and the API may still break (e.g. if the user passes the class for a read-only `List<LoggingEvent>`).

For example, even something as simple as this will cause a (to the API user strange, possibly untraceable) runtime exception:

```
new LogStore(IntList.class);
// Used with IntList defined as ...
public class IntList extends ArrayList<Integer> {
    @Override public Integer remove(int index) { return super.remove(index); }
}
```

If you choose to do the latter of the two options you will want to do something like this to check it really is a `List<LoggingEvent>`:

```
public LogStore(Class<? extends List> clazz) {
    assertListTypeArgsValid(clazz);
    // ... the rest of the above method implementation ...
}
private void assertListOk(Class<? extends List> clazz) {
    boolean verified = false;
    for (Type intr : clazz.getGenericInterfaces()) {
        if (!(intr instanceof ParameterizedType)) continue;

        ParameterizedType pIntr = (ParameterizedType)intr;
        if (pIntr.getRawType().getTypeName() != "java.util.List") continue;

        Type[] typeArgs = pIntr.getActualTypeArguments();
        if (typeArgs.length != 1) break;

        Class<?> tac = (Class<?>)typeArgs[0];
        verified = tac.isAssignableFrom(LoggingEvent.class);
        if (!verified) throw new IllegalArgumentException("clazz must be a List<LoggingEvent>, and is a: "
                + pIntr.getTypeName());
        break;
    }
    if (!verified) throw new IllegalArgumentException("clazz must be a List<LoggingEvent>");
}
```

Comment: "In this case this is safe to do..." Unless you give a `List` class that can't be `List<LogLine>`. e.g. if I have a `class IntList implements List<Integer>`

Comment: @newacct. I had assumed that the OP was providing a "list of `List<LoggingEvent>` choices" - if not, and this is to be used as an API then further checking may indeed required to prevent against such ridiculous usage. However even that is not fool-proof. The API user could pass the class for a read-only list implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, then yes; the simplest method I can think of, would be a constructor that takes a `Collection`. For example, [`ArrayList(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29).

```
List<SomeType> copyList = new ArrayList<>(original);
```

Or perhaps, you wanted something that returns a `List<T>` given an item `T`. Something like [`Collections.singletonList(T)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList%28T%29)

```
SomeType t = // ...
List<SomeType> al = Collections.singletonList(t);
```

Comment: It's more, I know I want a List of LoggingEvents but we are meant to make it so that it can be up to whoever wants to use our appender to specify what list type they want to use. So I have declared the private list as List<LoggingEvent> but the implementation of this List could be ArrayList, LinkedList or whatever else depending on what is specified when the constructor is called.

Comment: @Syzorr Then you [program to the interface](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/2970947).

Comment: Yep - I've been talking with friends regarding this as well and I probably phrased it really really badly. I'm only now really learning about generics and I had already been "programming to the interface"

What I was going for I finally figured out as something like:  
public MemoryAppender(Class<List> clazz) throws Exception {  
   super();  
   eventsLog = clazz.newInstance();  
}  
  
Still working on it but that is kind of what I was aiming for. Thank you for your feedback.